# Create array from object in aggregation mogodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document with this format

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c488e688e0dbe41183a22b7"),
    "id" : "d400003",
    "orderBC" : "20190123_165230",
    "orderTS" : 1548258750000.0,
    "value" : 1
}
```

---

i would like to have in final result

```
{
  "id": "d400003",
  "data": [ 15482587500000 , 1]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html), try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            id: 1,
            data: [ "$orderTS", "$value" ]
        }
    }
])
```